# NSLayoutManager: How to fill background colors where there are renderable glyphs only

Tags: ios, swift, core-text, textkit, nslayoutmanager

The default layout manager fills in the background color (specified via NSAttributedString .backgroundColor attribute) where there's no text (except for the last line).

[image]

I've managed to achieve the effect I want by sublclassing NSLayoutManager and overriding `func drawBackground(forGlyphRange glyphsToShow: NSRange, at origin: CGPoint)` as follows:

```swift
override func drawBackground(forGlyphRange glyphsToShow: NSRange, at origin: CGPoint) {
    guard let textContainer = textContainers.first, let textStorage = textStorage else { fatalError() }

    // This just takes the color of the first character assuming the entire container has the same background color.
    // To support ranges of different colours, you'll need to draw each glyph separately, querying the attributed string for the
    // background color attribute for the range of each character.
    guard textStorage.length > 0, let backgroundColor = textStorage.attribute(.backgroundColor, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIColor else { return }

    var lineRects = [CGRect]()

    // create an array of line rects to be drawn.
    enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: glyphsToShow) { (_, usedRect, _, range, _) in
        var usedRect = usedRect
        let locationOfLastGlyphInLine = NSMaxRange(range)-1
        // Remove the space at the end of each line (except last).
        if self.isThereAWhitespace(at: locationOfLastGlyphInLine) {
            let lastGlyphInLineWidth = self.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: NSRange(location: locationOfLastGlyphInLine, length: 1), in: textContainer).width
            usedRect.size.width -= lastGlyphInLineWidth
        }
        lineRects.append(usedRect)
    }

    lineRects = adjustRectsToContainerHeight(rects: lineRects, containerHeight: textContainer.size.height)

    for (lineNumber, lineRect) in lineRects.enumerated() {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        context.saveGState()
        context.setFillColor(backgroundColor.cgColor)
        context.fill(lineRect)
        context.restoreGState()
    }
}

private func isThereAWhitespace(at location: Int) -> Bool {
    return propertyForGlyph(at: location) == NSLayoutManager.GlyphProperty.elastic
}
```

[image]

However, this doesn't handle the possibility of having multiple colors specified by range in the attributed string. How might I achieve this? I've looked at `fillBackgroundRectArray` with little success.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/kimikaza/TagFieldDemoPlayground/blob/master/TagFieldsDemoPlayground.playground/Contents.swift This way you can have different attribute keys for each color.

Comment: Koen, thanks for this, it doesn't quite work over multiple lines, however

Comment: Yeah - In the end, I moved away from using attributes, and tracked the selected ranges myself, and colored them as appropriate. But I don't have those gaps like you show (after the word when), so it may also not work in your case.

Answer (score 4):

> How might I achieve this?

Heres' how I reached your goal to highlight the *" sit "* term in different colors inside the famous `Lorem ipsum...` that is huge enough to test on multiple lines.

All the basics that support the following code *(Swift 5.1, iOS 13)* are provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216224/3825084) and won't be copied here for clarity reason ⟹ they led to the result **1** hereafter.

[image]

In your case, you want to highlight some specific parts of a string which means that these elements should have dedicated key attributes due to their content ⟹ in my view, it's up to the `textStorage` to deal with it.

**MyTextStorage.swift**

```
// Sent when a modification appears via the 'replaceCharacters' method.
    override func processEditing() {

        var regEx: NSRegularExpression

        do {
            regEx = try NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: " sit ", options: .caseInsensitive)
            let stringLength = backingStorage.string.distance(from: backingStorage.string.startIndex,
                                                              to: backingStorage.string.endIndex)
            regEx.enumerateMatches(in: backingStorage.string,
                                   options: .reportCompletion,
                                   range: NSRange(location: 1, length: stringLength-1)) { (result, flags, stop) in

                                guard let result = result else { return }
                                self.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black, //To be seen above every colors.
                                                    NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor : UIColor.random()],
                                                   range: result.range)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }

        super.processEditing()
    }
}

//A random color is provided for each " sit " element to highlight the possible different colors in a string.
extension UIColor {
    static func random () -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
                       green: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
                       blue: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

If you build and run from here, you get the result **2** that shows a problem with each colored background of *" sit "* found in the text ⟹ there's an offset between the `lineFragment` and the colored background rectangles.

I went and see the `fillBackgroundRectArray` method you mentioned and about which Apple states that it *'fills background rectangles with a color'* and *'is the primitive method used by `drawBackground`'*: seems to be perfect here to correct the layout problem.

**MyLayoutManager.swift**

```
override func fillBackgroundRectArray(_ rectArray: UnsafePointer<CGRect>,
                                      count rectCount: Int,
                                      forCharacterRange charRange: NSRange,
                                      color: UIColor) {

    self.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: charRange) { (rect, usedRect, textContainer, glyphRange, stop) in

        var newRect = rectArray[0]
        newRect.origin.y = usedRect.origin.y + (usedRect.size.height / 4.0)
        newRect.size.height = usedRect.size.height / 2.0

        let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        currentContext?.saveGState()
        currentContext?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        currentContext?.fill(newRect)

        currentContext?.restoreGState()
    }
}
```

Parameters adjustments need to be explored in depth to have a generic formula but for the example it works fine as is.

Finally, we get the result **3** that **enables the possibility of having multiple colors specified by range in the attributed string** once the conditions of the regular expression are adapted.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could bypass using the attributes at all, like this:

So first I defined this struct:

```
struct HighlightBackground {
    let range: NSRange
    let color: NSColor
}
```

Then in my NSTextView subclass:

```
var highlightBackgrounds = [HighlightBackground]()

override func setSelectedRanges(_ ranges: [NSValue], affinity: NSSelectionAffinity, stillSelecting stillSelectingFlag: Bool) {
    if stillSelectingFlag == false {
        return
    }

 // remove old ranges first
    highlightBackgrounds = highlightBackgrounds.filter { $0.color != .green }

    for value in ranges {
        let range = value.rangeValue

        highlightBackgrounds.append(HighlightBackground(range: range, color: .green))
    }

    super.setSelectedRanges(ranges, affinity: affinity, stillSelecting: stillSelectingFlag)
}
```

And then call this from your `draw(_ rect: NSRect)` method:

```
func showBackgrounds() {
    guard
        let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext,
        let lm = self.layoutManager
    else { return }

    context.saveGState()
    //        context.translateBy(x: origin.x, y: origin.y)

    for bg in highlightBackgrounds {
        bg.color.setFill()

        let glRange = lm.glyphRange(forCharacterRange: bg.range, actualCharacterRange: nil)    
        for rect in lm.rectsForGlyphRange(glRange) {    
            let path = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, xRadius: selectedTextCornerRadius, yRadius: selectedTextCornerRadius)
            path.fill()
        }
    }

    context.restoreGState()
}
```

Finally, you'll need this in your NSLayoutManager subclass, although you probably could also put it in the NSTextView subclass:

```
func rectsForGlyphRange(_ glyphsToShow: NSRange) -> [NSRect] {

    var rects = [NSRect]()
    guard
        let tc = textContainer(forGlyphAt: glyphsToShow.location, effectiveRange: nil)
    else { return rects }

    enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: glyphsToShow) { _, _, _, effectiveRange, _ in
        let rect = self.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: NSIntersectionRange(glyphsToShow, effectiveRange), in: tc)
        rects.append(rect)
    }

    return rects
}
```

Hopefully, this works also in your case.